# How can I display all the data from a table?

Tags: php, loops, html-table

How can I display all the data from a table inside a table tag using loops?
Here is my code:

```
     <table width="380px">
              <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $left_bread['recipe'];?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $left_bread['name'];?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $left_bread['scale_date'];?></td>
               </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: You'd have to use loops and echo the table rows manually. Are you retrieving your data from a database?

Comment: i guess, i got the answer below..i was only lacking on a query to get the data from the database..thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your code is lacking..from what i see it lacks a foreach(). maybe you should try this,

```
<?php foreach($your_variable as $your_alias):?>
<table width="380px">
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $your_alias['recipe'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $your_alias['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $your_alias['scale_date'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I think that's it, if what you want is display data dynamically from a query, then this will do, knowing that $your_variable contains a query which will get recipe,name and scale_date. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use foreach  to acces your data ..

```
//$data for example contains your fetched results from the database 

// this will lopp until it contains results
<?php
foreach( $data as $left_bread ) {

<table width="380px">
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $left_bread['recipe'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $left_bread['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $left_bread['scale_date'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>

}

  ?>
```